# Angular validator: How to unsubscribe to valueChanges from parent component?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-validation

*Using Angular 11*

I have a regular component with several form controls like so, and with all the validators in a separate file to keep things clean. In some of the validator functions, I'm subscribing to the `valueChanges` event on certain controls.

I'm wondering how I can unsubscribe to those subscriptions when the parent component is destroyed, or how to keep track of them within my `validators.ts` file to destroy them there. I'm still trying to get my head around RxJS, so I'm no pro with that yet. Hoping the way to do this is obvious to someone here.

**Component**

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms'
import { validator1, validator2 } from './validators'

@Component()

export class MyForm implements OnInit {
  theForm: FormGroup
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }
  ngOnInit() {}

  createForm() {
    this.theForm = this.fb.group({
      field1: ['', [validator1, validator2]],
      field2: ['', Validators.minLength(10)]
      ...
    })
  }
}
```

**validator.ts**

*this is just a plain Typscript file with the validator functions exported.*

```
export function validator1() {
  return (thisControl: FormControl) => {
    const otherControl = control.parent.get('field2') as FormControl
    otherControl.valueChanges.subscribe(() => { // <=== How to unsubscribe to this?
      thisControl.updateValueAndValidity();
    })
    
    if (isValid(thisControl.value)) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return { 'invalidValue': true }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: **never**, **never** subscribe inside a validator -a validator is executed several times-. You need subscribe outside, after create the formGroup and unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy of the component

Comment: That's a very good point; I wish I knew that a long time ago, because I'm sure I copied that code from somewhere.

Comment: I've implemented that now in my code, and it's all working, so thank you. If you want to make that an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Ok, so I thought it was working, but it turns out that after a few changes, it seems something with the valueChanges subscriptions is multiplying the time something takes to update by 7 (since I set 7 subscriptions in ngOnInit), so after a few updates I start getting Zone.js violations in the console saying "Click handler took 1790ms" and the next is 8s, then 24s, until the page is basically unresponsive. I don't know why it's so creeping slow now.